# Issue with Ionic and Clappr video player

Tags: android, ionic-framework, clappr

I'm trying to run a simple ionic app with a video player (clappr) inside,
I get this event error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:62904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcEvent' of undefined
```

The problem goes off once I remove this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.clappr.io/latest/clappr.js"></script>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using:

`$('#SomeItem').srcEvent()` ... or something like that (I'm not familiar with the clappr).

But the error says that (**SomeItem**) is undefined. Try to use `console.log(SomeItem)` to check item status.

Comment: I'm debugging on a fresh ionic app so I didn't add any additional code to the start up application, but the good news is that I found the source of the problem (It's not an angular incompatibility problem, but it's related to an ionic tag, somethings happens when I add this tag "<ion-side-menu-content>", I'm not touching any js script, also there is no such call of srcEvent() inside clappr script